# creating an ember-data application serialzer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I've been trying to use ember data for a few days now. The problem is the api I have does not match the strcuture ember-data would like to receive.

item:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "rodzzlessa",
        "slug": "rodzzlessa"
     }
}
```

collection:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 34,
        "name": "HDG common nails 50lbs",
        "slug": "hdg-common-nails-50lbs4569",
        "description": "Accusantium ipsam impedit omnis sint dolorum.",
        "image_src": "nail-box-angle.png",
        "categories": {
            "data": [
                {
                     "id": 2,
                     "name": "nails",
                    "image_src": "nails-icon.png"
                }
             ]
         }
     }
  ]
}
```

from what I've seen I need to modify the extractSingle and extractArray methods. There really isn't an online resource showing what the methods are really doing and how to modify them. I check the ember-data api guide but the example is so specific and its not an application serializer so it seems much easier the problem they are solving. I tried finding an ember-data book but they don't exist yet. Are there any online resources to help me?

/***** UPDATE SO FAR ******/

So I was able to create a application serializer to handle the collection and items:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

    extractArray: function(store, typeClass, payload) {
        var root_key = Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize(typeClass.typeKey);

        payload[root_key] = payload.data;
        delete payload.data;

        return this._super(store, typeClass, payload);
    },

    extractSingle: function(store, typeClass, payload, id){
        var root_key = typeClass.typeKey;

        payload[root_key] = payload.data;
        delete payload.data;

        return this._super(store, typeClass, payload, id);
    }
});
```

Now the only problem I have is dealing with relationships I started messing around with the normalize method this is what I have so far:

```
normalize: function(typeClass, hash, prop){
        self = this;

        typeClass.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship){
            if(relationship.kind === "hasMany"){
                if( ! hash[key]){
                    return hash;
                }

                var hashed = hash[key].data;

                hash[key] = hashed;

                return hashed;
            }
        });

        return this._super(typeClass, hash, prop);
    }
```

Now the error I get from ember-data is this:

```
Assertion Failed: Ember Data expected a number or string to represent the record(s) in the `categories` relationship instead it found an object
```

Comment: Try reading the source code for the methods you are attempting to use.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code. I can help but I'm not going to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: @ChristopherMilne check my updates

Comment: why are you deleting payload.data in extractArray and extractSingle?